# What is the best way to get into game development and learn how to program with graphics?

Tags: c++, graphics, education

I'm a 16 year old learning C++. My friend and I have dreams of starting our own indie game company and we would, both, like to know how to get into game development.

One of our major questions is: How does one tie in graphics with programming (mainly C++)

Thanks in advance,

Tux

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately this site is not the best place for a question like this. We value specific questions that have specific and objective answers. This question will introduce discussion and personal biases. My advice for you is to do some Googling and look up DirectX, OpenGL, SDL, and frameworks/engines built around them.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking around and using what you like. I'll list some libraries that are commonly used by game developers writing 2D games in C++. I'll try my best to sound unbiased.

**SDL**
Low-level library (easiest to understand for beginners) with basic image-blitting.

**SFML**
High-level library with networking, sound output, & complex shape/sprite actions.

**Haaf's Game Engine**
High-level library with basic sprite actions & sound output (meant for beginners).

Since you're just starting, I'd suggest SDL. It's good for the first game or two. Once you're more comfortable with the language, you could try other things.

[LazyFoo's tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/index.php) are great SDL tutorials for people who are still learning C++.

Comment: +1 for Haaf's Game Engine, great for beginners + Open source!